# Loopback delete multiple relations

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I'm trying to destroy multiple relations linked to a model from my angular application.

in my person.json I have two relations:

```
  "messageGroups": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "messageGroup"
    },
    "messageStudents": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "messageStudent"
    }
```

These work fine.
However I want to delete multiple messageGroups and messageStudents for a person in one call. Rather than use multiple calls to Person.messageGroups.destroyById(...) and Person.messageStudents.destroyById(...)

My initial thought was to make a remote method in my person.js file that accepts a personId and an object containing ids for messageGroups and messageStudents.

But I'm unable to write working code.
My last attempt looks like this:

```
Person.destroyTargetsFromMessage = function (personId, assignees, callback) {
        for(var i in assignees.studentIds){
            Person.messageStudents.destroyById({'id': personId, 'fk': assignees.studentIds[i]});
        }
        for(var i in assignees.groupIds){
            Person.messageGroups.destroyById({'id': personId, 'fk': assignees.groupIds[i]});
        }
        callback();
    };
```

Or would the proper way to do this use multiple calls to my API after all?

**UPDATE**

I've written this code that brings me closer to my goal:

```
Person.destroyTargetsFromMessage = function (personId, assignees, callback) {
        Person.findById(teacherId, function(err, targetPerson){
            for(var i in assignees.studentIds){
                targetPerson.messageStudents.findById(assignees.studentIds[i], function(err, student){
                    callback(null, student);
                    console.log(student);
                });
            }
            for(var i in assignees.groupIds){
                targetPerson.messageGroups.findById(assignees.groupIds[i], function(err, group){
                    callback(null, group);
                    console.log(group);
                });
            }
            callback();
        });
};
```

The only problem is that I cannot call destroyById on my targetPerson relations, but findById seems to be working just fine.

**SOLVED**

the method that deletes my relations is `destroy`, not `destroyById`

Comment: What happens when you run your remoteMethod?I think you can get more debug detail by running `$ DEBUG=strong-remoting:remotes node .` but I'm not on my home computer to check.

Comment: Also I think you need to reference your other models like so: `app.Models.MessageStudent.destroyById` http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Working+with+LoopBack+objects#WorkingwithLoopBackobjects-Gettingreferencestomodels

Comment: The error I'm receiving is "Cannot call method 'destroyById' of undefined".

Comment: then the `blah` in `blah.destroyById` is indeed undefined, go ahead and paste the line here, i think with @conradj's suggestion that line can be edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method that deletes my relations is `destroy`, not `destroyById`